# Timer doesn't work due to unresponsive UI

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

The C# window which performs a data pull from SQL stored procedure, doesn't show 'Time Elapsed' because the Timer control doesn't seem to work.

One of my applications, that uses Timer control - doesn't seem to keep the timer ticking when it's processing.

If I perform `Timer.Start()` on Form_Load, it seems to work fine. However `Timer.Start()` prior to starting of a data pull (which takes about 2-3 minutes) seems to not-work.

Timer is enabled.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrTime.Start();
    if (txtEmployeeNumber.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        connectDB(); //Connects to Database, Executes a Stored Procedure, Prepares a response String, and assigns response to a Textbox. All of which takes 2-3 minutes.
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!");
    }
     tmrTime.Stop();
}



private void tmrTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTimer.Text = "Time Elapsed : " + (DateTime.Now - dtStart).Seconds + " second(s)";
}
```

Comment: Aren't you stopping your timer right after starting it after your IF-block, in your button-code?

Comment: What kind of timer are you using?

Comment: @StackingForHeap Yes - but it takes a while to get there. The connectDB(); takes about 2-3 minutes of processing time.

Comment: @Steve System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: So you assume the db is not processing in the background so that the button just closes the timer as soon as the call to db has been made? What kind of timer are you using?

Comment: @StackingForHeap Yes and No. The DB does take a good 2-3 minutes and I can see it. While this is happening, the UI is unresponsive and the timer doesn't change/tick at all. I use System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: Please add at least the definition for `connectDB`

Comment: Then you should use the  BackgroundWorker (class) and its ProgressChanged -event to update your timer/GUI.

Comment: Slow dbase queries must not hang the UI thread.  Use a worker thread instead, Task or BackgroundWorker classses.

Comment: Do you want to show a progress in your operation? Like a progress bar and not just the total time required by the long operation right?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - added some comments. Believe those should satisfy understanding the nature of the issue. But if it helps I'll write the code for this method.

Comment: @Steve Yes, at least some sort of. It could take 2 minutes or 3 or 20, no way of knowing. I'd want to see an elapsed time since the button click. Does that clarify?

Comment: @HansPassant yes, and that was my understanding as well. Weird that it does block the UI

Comment: @tempidope Why is it weird to you that running a bunch of long running operations in the UI thread blocks the UI thread?  What else could it do?

Comment: The CLR has workarounds for getting this wrong, blocking an STA thread is very troublesome.  But it is limited, your UI might paint but it is not going to respond to the mouse or keyboard and timers will not tick.

Comment: If you have an employee that can only do 1 thing at a time in the order it was given to them then it's natural that they cannot count from 1 to N while busy crunching away at a database. It's well known in windows programming that anything that cannot return quickly should not be on the main thread (because the UI shares it). If the long running process is just your application waiting on the response to something outside of your code base (such as a remote API call) you don't need a background thread, you can just use async programming.

Answer (score 3):

Should do this

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// here execute your DB call
sw.Stop();
txtTimer.Text = string.Format("Time Elapsed : {0}", sw);
```

Now, if you do this via background thread, your screen should be responsive. Just make sure to synchronize control (text box). You can start with `BackgroundWorker` and do this on `DoWork`. Then on complete, read data and set control value

**UPDATE**

If you want time of execution show on form, do this. This is all you need

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private DateTime _startTime;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var span = (DateTime.Now - _startTime);
        label1.Text = string.Format("Elapsed: {0}", span);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        _timer.Start();
        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();


    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // run query here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP really wants. I think that they want some kind of progress while the long operation runs. Something like a progress bar. In this way you give only the total time required by the operation.

Comment: They can't report progress on a single query since they don't know how many records fetched and how many to go. In this case they can show an "approximate" progress bar, which is fake.

Comment: No one's talking about reporting the number of records. I assumed from the question that he wants to continually see the timer tick up in the textbox. But because the DB call blocks the thread, he doesn't see the time increment.

Comment: Exactly @TyCobb

Comment: @tempidope As explained by comments under your question (and here) your UI thread is busy doing the query. While inside that code the UI thread cannot execute updates of your label. You need to switch sides. The long operation runs in background while the UI thread updates the label.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` died when `async/await` was introduced, so downvote for deprecated practices

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This is irrelevant to the question. Bottom line is, separate thread of execution and display. I could use `ThreadPool` if I had time to write it. BGWorker is the simple way to express what needs to be done. Besides, may be OP is still in FW3.5? In fact, I used existing project which is FW3.5 -) enjoy

Comment: @T.S. The OP doesn't have CPU bound work to do, so no, that wouldn't be appropriate either.  You shouldn't be creating a background thread or thread pool thread just to have it sit around doing nothing any more than you should have the UI thread doing that.

Comment: @Servy if you load huge chunk of data it is better to do on a different thread if you want to keep screen responsive

Comment: @T.S. If you're doing a bunch of CPU bound processing of that data, sure, that should be done in a background thread.  The OP only indicates that there's executing a DB query.  If there is long running CPU bound processing on the results, a background thread should only be used for said processing, not to wait for the DB to do its work.  Loading the results into the UI *can't* be done in a background thread; only the UI thread can access UI elements.  That's...the whole point of the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy This is matter of opinion. OP stated that data pool takes 2-3 minutes. Screen will be frozen without use of a different thread. Data can be loaded into Dataset or List and then bound. I rest my case

Comment: @T.S. No, that's false.  The UI thread needs to not block.  That doesn't mean you need to create some other thread to do nothing that whole time.  The proper course of action is to do the work asynchronously, such that *no* thread is blocked.  It's trivially easy to solve this type of problem without *ever* using any non-UI thread.  That you don't understand that indicates you shouldn't be answering these kinds of questions.

Comment: So you think that's irrelevant to create threads that do nothing? I'll take it you don't care at all about performance either. I/O bound work should be done with TPL. Only because you are in .NET 3.5 doesn't mean the OP is tied to that extremely old version too

Comment: @Servy Ok, dude. This is free world. I can answer questions, you can downvote if you wish. You could post your answer and perhaps I could learn something.

Comment: The BackgroundThread you are creating that only waits for a DB to respond

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It loads data for 2-3 minutes and once done - dies, and  user can check the grid (for example).

Answer (score -3):

Maybe better solution would be to use Stopwatch?
Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:
After Steve's comment - I added some usability for Stopwatch class

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    DoSomething();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"DoSomething() code took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms to run.");

    sw.Restart();
    DoSomethingElse();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingElse() code took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms to run.");
}
```

Note - watch out for weird calculations while debugging - it will continue to count as you put a breakpoint at spots in your code.

Comment: Maybe a better answer would show how to use a Stopwatch in this context?

Comment: Well that's better, but I think that the OP wants to show some kind of timer progress with its code. You can't do it with a Stopwatch. Not my downvote though.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but this will still block the UI thread (note this is happening in a `Click` event)